# Is it possible to combine these two arrays here in JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The first array is looks like:

```js
[
  0：{program: id_1},
  1: {program: id_2}
]
```

The second array is:

```js
[
  0: [
    0: {lesson: name_1},
    1: {lesson: name_2}
  ],
  1: [
    0: {lesson: name_3}
  ]
]
```

What I tried to do is I want combine the two arrays like this:

```js
[
 0：{
   program:id_1,
   [
     0: {lesson: name_1},
     1: {lesson: name_2}
   ]
 },
 1: {
   program: id_2,
   [
     0: {lesson: name_3}
   ]
 }
]
```

I am not sure if it is possible, I tried many ways, but all didn't work. Any help will be great, thanks

Comment: None of those 3 code blocks have valid Javascript syntax

Comment: Including the index makes it a little confusing to read

Comment: So how do they relate to each other? By index? The output is also invalid so unclear what it should actually look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this example:

```
    var id_1 = 11, id_2 = 12;
    var name_1 = 'lession 1', name_2 = 'lession 2', name_3 = 'lession 3';

    var arr1 = [
        {program: id_1},
        {program: id_2}
    ];

    var arr2 = [
        [
            {lesson: name_1},
            {lesson: name_2}
        ],
        [
            {lesson: name_3}
        ]
    ];

    arr1.map((ar, index) => {
        ar.lessons = [];
        arr2[index].map(ar2 => {
            ar.lessons.push(ar2);
        })
    });
    console.log(arr1);
```

**Here is the picture of console.log**

[image: picture of console.log]

Answer (score -1):

You definitely don't need the index numbers. Try storing them in a variable using the spread operator like so.

```
var 
  arr1 = [{program:"id_1"},{program:"id_2"}],
  arr2 = [[{lesson:"name_1"},{lesson:"name_2"}],[{lesson:"name_3"}]],
  newArr = [...arr1, ...arr2]; 
console.log(newArr);
```

You will get something that looks like this:

```
   [
     {program: "id_1"},
     {program: "id_2"},
     [{lesson: "name_1"},{lesson: "name_2"}],
     [{lesson: "name_3"}]
   ]
```